# Foreach equivalent function in Unity javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, unity-game-engine, foreach

I'm creating charged particle simulator in Unity3D and need to apply a function to each object within an array.

The array is defined as

```
var mcp = new Array(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MovingChargedParticle"));
```

My current function to affect each object within the array is:

```
function applyMagneticForce(particle1, particle2){

    for (MovingChargedParticle mcp in mcp){

    var NewForce : Vector3.zero;

    var distance=Vector3.Distance(particle1.transform.position, particle2.transform.position);
    var force=1000 * cp.charge * mcp.charge / Mathf.Pow (distance, 2);

    NewForce += force * distance * cycleinterval;    

    }
}
```

For now, cp.charge and mcp.charge are placeholders for calling a public var on other objects..something else I haven't figured out.

Comment: You know what .. "unityscript" is totally deprecated.  You really have to change to c#.  (Fortunately it is extremely easy - it's much easier.)  Indeed, simply use List<> in Unity, realistically you never use arrays for any reason.

Comment: Hey Joe, you pointed that out on an earlier question I posted. Which I do totally appreciate, and will absolutely use that advice for the next project I start. However, I'd like to finish this project out using javascript since I've already completed so much of it.. I'll try using List<> instead.

Comment: understood; sorry for repeat.  you know, it's *incredibly* difficult to do actual OO stuff in javascript.  cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Something like this:**

```
var objects : GameObject[] = FindObjectsOfType(GameObject) as GameObject[];

for(var item : GameObject in objects)
{
    print (item.transform.position);
}
```